# Google or Bing Maps Class or Plugin

Tags: php, class, google-maps, plugins, bing-maps

I have searched the web and I can't seem to find any google or bing map php classes or plugins that are up to date and simple.

I am building a real estate search site and I am looking for a simple php class do display multiple addresses on a map. I was hoping to find a php class or plugin where all i would have to do is "requireonce" the class/plugin and addresses and the class/plugin would do all the work.

I am open to using google or bing maps.  Does anyone know of any php classes/plugins that would help accomplish this without having to hand code the entire functionality.

Thank you.

Comment: I'd suggest not using any plugins. The Google Maps API is easy enough to use directly, it's well documented and well supported. Obscure plugins introduce more problems than they solve and they limit your chances of getting support. Do not get seduced by the word "easy". :-)

Answer (score 2):

Google Maps and Bing maps are client-side (JavaScript-powered), that's why you won't find any PHP libraries for it.

For displaying places of interest on a map, you want to fetch your items from the database and then add them to your map using JavaScript. In Google Maps, this would look something like this:

```
// instantiate the map
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.673830, -4.746093),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    zoom: 8
});

// create an InfoWindow
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

// fetch results from a PHP script
// assumes results are returned as a JSON-encoded array
$.getJSON('script.php', function(results) {
    $.each(results, function(i, result) {
        // create a market representing place of interest
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(result.latitude, result.longitude);
            title: result.title
        });

        // display information in infowindow on click
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent(result.content);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    });
});
```

Hopefully this will get you started. Check out the documentation for the [Google Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/), which has a comprehensive guide to the API, as well as numerous samples.